# Account invitations only work for logged in users

Tags: drone.io

If you send out an invitation to a new user from self-hosted Drone they are redirected to the login form, unless they are already logged in with another account - then they are redirected to the account completion form (as expected). Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in the next release (0.3) https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/450